# Uninstall Spring

Tags: spring, maven, ant

I have installed the spring using maven-ant:

```
  <dependency
            groupId="org.springframework"
            artifactId="spring-context"
            version="3.2.4.RELEASE"
        />
```

I am trying to uninstall the spring and install it again. When I run the code it doesn't install it. Is there anyway I can get rid of the spring totally and install it again?

Comment: Maven automatically installs the requested version, why would you need to "uninstall" it? You'll just end up with the same binary.

Comment: I am testing and documenting the code. I needed the snapshot of maven installing the spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution:

you need to go to your maven user directory and **.m2 hidden folder**, repository and you can delete whatever you don't want.